# modifying current log4j2 configuration during runtime

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to modify the current configuration of log4j2 during runtime in code.

I am following the directions here -

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent
 under Programmatically Modifying the Current Configuration after Initialization.

I am having trouble with this line -

```
 Layout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout(PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN, config, null,
        null,null, null);
```

as that code will not work, the constructor in the API is completely different than that. The constructor in the API is requesting that you supply a Pattern Selector which I cant seem to find much info on, I tried using DefaultSelector, and using the two selectors I found here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html (Marker Pattern Selector and Script Pattern Selector) and tried adding import statements for them but my program cannot find those classes.

Should I use the

```
createDefaultLayout(Configuration configuration)
```

method of PatternLayout instead as that will create a pattern layout with default options of the provided configuration?

One thing I noticed is under the createLayout method I am having trouble with, it says this underneath it -

```
Deprecated. 
Use newBuilder() instead. This will be private in a future version.
```

does this mean that this method is becoming obsolete now and I shouldnt be using it at all? Its requesting to use newBuilder which creates a builder for a custom pattern layout?

This API -

```
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/PatternLayout.Builder.html
```

seems to be a builder that will let me provide a configuration file, and has methods to build your own custom pattern layout? (However, there is a method for withPatternSelector which I cant find anything about so I hope that it will just use default if I do not specify a Pattern Selector?)

Any idea on which method would be better to change log4j2 configurations in code during runtime? or if there is a third method better than both of them you know of?

Basically, I want to be able to change the number of, for example, files to save (default rollover strategy) or the interval of days in timebasedtriggeringpolicy.

is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks for any help.